# Where to start? Facebook flash server game

Tags: flash

Im trying to teach myself how to make games and apps.

I want to try and make a myspace mobsters type game. A 2D game that allows players to interact via attacks/comments and level up.

Its a very overwhelming start, just looking for tips on where to start. What programs i should be getting to know for coding and where to research, what Would be needed for server interaction?

Thanks for any pointers!

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in game design it is best to start small and then work your way up.  If you are completely new to programing, I suggest you start with Python's Pygame and this tutorial http://programarcadegames.com/